# Error when encoding a pdf file into a JSON string

Tags: java, json, utf-8, jackson

I want to read the contents of a pdf file and send it over to server in a JSON String. I used google guava library to read the contents of the pdf file into a string. Then I used jettison JSON library to escape the required characters that will clash with JSON.

```
String content = Files.toString(new File("C:/Users/Sudhagar/Desktop/GAME.pdf"), Charset.defaultCharset());

String escapedContent = org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.quote(content);
```

I set the default charset for the JVM to be UTF-8.

The resultant JSON string is created as follows,

```
String respStr = "{\n";
respStr = respStr + "\"mimetype\" : \"" + "text/plain" + "\",\n";
respStr = respStr + "\"value\" : " + escapedContent + "\n";
respStr = respStr + "}\n";
System.out.println(respStr);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(respStr);
httpput.setEntity(entity);
```

When I send this JSON to the server I get an exception,

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xfc  at [Source: [B@5733c2; line: 3, column: 25]
```

I would like to know if there is any error in this approach or any other approach for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a PDF file should be considered as opaque binary data, just like an image or encrypted data.

*Don't* read it as if it were a plain text file. Treat it as you would other binary data - which probably means base64-encoding it for the sake of JSON.